# Reshape tensors of unknown shape with tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say that in my function I have to deal with input tensors of shape [4,3,2,1] and [5,4,3,2,1]. I want to reshape them in such a way that the last two dimensions are swapped, e.g., to [4,3,1,2]. In eager mode this is easy, but when I try to wrap my function using `@tf.function` the following error is thrown:

`OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic tf.Tensor is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.`

The code in question is as follows:

```
tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[4, 3, 2, 1])

    @tf.function
    def my_func():
        reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, shape=[*tf.shape(tensor)[:-2], tf.shape(tensor)[-1], tf.shape(tensor)[-2]])
        return reshaped

    logging.info(my_func())
```

It looks like tensorflow does not like the `[:-2]` notation, but I don't really know how else I should solve this problem in an elegant and well-readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing the tensor like that in `Graph` mode unfortunately does not work, but I think you can use `tf.transpose`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[4, 3, 2, 1])

@tf.function
def my_func():
  rank = tf.rank(tensor)
  some_magic = tf.concat([tf.zeros((rank - 2,), dtype=tf.int32), [1, -1]], axis=-1)
  reshaped = tf.transpose(tensor, perm = tf.range(rank) + some_magic)
  return reshaped

print(my_func().shape)
# (4, 3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my main problem comes not from the permutation itself but rather the fact that I have to deal with both tensors of rank 4 and tensors of rank 5, i.e., if I wanted to transpose the last two dimensions `perm` should be equal to either `[0,1,3,2]` or `[0,1,2,4,3]`, based on the input. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible to pass a `perm` tensor as an argument every time you want to reshape? I have a feeling your question is missing important details

Comment: I'm dealing with a deep learning application where I'm trying to implement a special kind of attention algorithm. I want to support multi-head attention, which introduces an additional dimension to my input tensors, e.g., the tensors can be of shape [batch_size, sequence_length, dimension] or [batch_size, amount_heads, sequence_length, dimension]. I wanted all my operations to work regardless of the shape of the input. In theory I could hard code these cases, but that doesn't seem very elegant. Passing `perm` would not really work as I apply a lot of `tf.reshape`s and other operations.